# Prohibit separating different fields into new lines in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, beamerposter

I am using this template (https://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster) which is based on `beamerposter` to create a conference poster. The bibliography list generated automatically separates different fields (author, title, journal etc.) into new lines which wastes a lot of space. I have tried several different bibliographystyle but the problem remains. Guess the origin is in the `.sty` files coming with the template but could not locate the spot to modify.

Is there a way to disable such separation?

Thanks.
[image]

Please see comment for MWEB

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you please make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: Especially please tell us, if you use bibtex or biblatex

Comment: Yes - MWEB as in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8xqHOnvFSb-QVZtTHRQclktaE0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could not find the linebreaks in the `.sty` file of your template, because they origin from beamer itself. For example the default definition for the title is

```
\defbeamertemplate*{bibliography entry title}{default}{\par}
```

which will start the title in a new paragraph. This can be changed with

```
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
```

---

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} % Use the beamerposter package for laying out the poster

\usetheme{confposter} % Use the confposter theme supplied with this template

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}

\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth} % Separation width (white space) between columns
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth} % Width of one column

\title{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} % Poster title

\author{John Smith, James Smith and Jane Smith} % Author(s)

\institute{Department and University Name} % Institution(s)

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry article}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] 

\begin{columns}[t] 

\begin{column}{\onecolwid} 

Blabla \cite{Smith:2012qr}
Blabla \cite{Smith:2013jd}

\begin{block}{References}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{sample.bib}

\end{block}

\end{column} % End of the third column

\end{columns} % End of all the columns in the poster

\end{frame} % End of the enclosing frame

\end{document}
```

[image]